# Stream plot with varying colours in matplotlib giving 2 cmaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, data-visualization, subplot

A [stream plot, or streamline plot, is used to display 2D vector fields](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/plot_streamplot.html). I am creating a stream plot with varying colors in Python but am getting two different `cmap` on the side. The code used is almost identical to the help file but I am getting multiple cmaps on the third plot. How does one remove the second cmap?

Below is the code that I used followed by the output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,20),np.linspace(-5,5,20))

xdot = y
ydot = -2*x - 3*y

# subplot2grid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0, 1))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 0))
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 1))

# Plot 1
Q = ax1.quiver(x, y, xdot, ydot, scale=500, angles='xy') # Quiver key
ax1.quiverkey(Q,-10,22.5,30,'5.1.8',coordinates='data',color='k')
ax1.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
ax1.set_title('Quiver plot 6.1.1')

# Plot 2
strm  = ax2.streamplot(x, y, xdot, ydot, density=1, color='k', linewidth=2) # streamplot(X,Y,u,v)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines)
ax2.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
ax2.set_title('Stream plot of 6.1.1')

# Plot 4
strm  = ax4.streamplot(x, y, xdot, ydot, density=1, color=xdot, linewidth=2, cmap='autumn') # streamplot(X,Y,u,v, density = 1)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines, ax=ax4)
ax4.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='Stream plot of 6.1.1 with varying color')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The help file for the [stream plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/plot_streamplot.html) has an example that worked to implement this problem that worked as desired. This is what I used to plot the original stream plot.

1. [Stream plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-constrainedlayout-guide-py)
2. [Constrained Layout Guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-constrainedlayout-guide-py)

### Summary

So to summarize my question. How does one remove the two color maps at the side?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `fig.colorbar(strm.lines)` under `# Plot 2`

Comment: @BigBen I just noticed now and felt like the biggest chop. Thanks hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the `ax` of the `ax2.streamplot`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,20),np.linspace(-5,5,20))

xdot = y
ydot = -2*x - 3*y

# subplot2grid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0, 1))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 0))
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 1))

# Plot 1
Q = ax1.quiver(x, y, xdot, ydot, scale=500, angles='xy') # Quiver key
ax1.quiverkey(Q,-10,22.5,30,'5.1.8',coordinates='data',color='k')
ax1.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
ax1.set_title('Quiver plot 6.1.1')

# Plot 2
strm  = ax2.streamplot(x, y, xdot, ydot, density=1, color='k', linewidth=2) # streamplot(X,Y,u,v)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines, ax = ax2) # <--- TO BE DELETED
ax2.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
ax2.set_title('Stream plot of 6.1.1')

# Plot 4
strm  = ax4.streamplot(x, y, xdot, ydot, density=1, color=xdot, linewidth=2, cmap='autumn') # streamplot(X,Y,u,v, density = 1)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines, ax=ax4)
ax4.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='Stream plot of 6.1.1 with varying color')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can delete the above line of code in order to remove the undesired colorbar:

[image]